# How Can I Pass Data from Array in didLoadObjects to cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, arrays, storyboard, restkit

So, I'm using RestKit to access a webservice and retrive data from there.
So far I have two views, and that part of retrieving the data is fine, and I get the 100 objects I need, saving them into an array called "songs".

Here is didLoadObjects:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects {
    NSLog(@" Reached didLoadObjects: %d", [objects count]);

    self.songs = objects;
    NSLog(@"%@",self.songs);
}
```

Ok, I have two views, and the problem is, of course, on the second one. I'm using Storyboards. I gave the tableView cell an identifier called "TopListCellIdentifier".

So, I get the objects, all the 100 of them are "printed" in the command line, but the problem starts when I try to access the data from the array inside cellForRowAtIndexPath, something which has to be done because I have a custom tableViewCell displaying the info I need (sons, artists, covers, stuff like that). So, when I start the app, the first view is fine, but the second has 100 cells, but no info. Here is the cellForRowAtIndexPath code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *TopListCellIdentifier = @"TopListCellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TopListCellIdentifier];

    // Loading the Cover Images in the Background
    // Cover Image: Tag 1
    [((HJManagedImageV*)[cell viewWithTag:1]) clear];
    HJManagedImageV* thumbImage = ((HJManagedImageV*)[cell viewWithTag:1]);
    NSString *thumbUrl = [[self.songs objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] thumbnail];

    thumbImage.url = [NSURL URLWithString:thumbUrl];
    [[ImageHandler sharedHandler].imgManager manage:thumbImage];

    //Song and Artist: Tag 2 and 3
    ((UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2]).text = [[self.songs objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] title];
    ((UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:3]).text = [[self.songs objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] artist];

    //Arrow Up/Down/Same: Tag 4
    //TODO

    //Position Number: Tag 5
    ((UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:5]).text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.", [indexPath row]+1];

    return cell;
}
```

I've tried to put a debugger in the first line of cellRow(...) but the program doesn't enter there. I feel like i'm forgetting about something very simple, but I can't seem to figure out what.

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You're never initing a new cell.  You need to add a line like :

```
if (nil == cell)
    cell = [[UITalbeViewCell alloc] init...
```

after your call to

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TopListCellIdentifier];
```

Comment: You don't need to for ios5+ (as long as his cell identifier exists) and he **is** getting cells, they are just empty.

Comment: Can you put some code in detail, please? Or some example, please.

Comment: That's what I thought. I don't to do that for iOS 5. Still I can't print the damn cells...:/